# How to handle checkbox list, complex form like a pro in Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Previously, in the old days, we use `[]` in the input *name* to send checkbox list data as array to PHP server

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="C/C++"> C/C++
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="Java"> Java
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="PHP"> PHP
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In the server (PHP), the *check_list* will be an array

```
$_POST['check_list']; //an array, e.g.: [ 'Java', 'PHP']
```

Now, with Angular4, let say, I have a questionnaire with many items, each item has many checkboxes, for example:

```
Question1: What is your name?
           __________________

Question2: What fruits do you like?
    [ ] Banana
    [ ] Kiwi
    [ ] Durian

Question3: What animals do you like?
    [ ] Cat
    [ ] Dog
    [ ] Dolphin
```

If I am going to implement this form in Angular4 with reactive form, then I need to create those `form control` with `formBuilder`

```
//note: "private fb: FormBuilder " is injected in the constructor
createForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
        q1: '',
        q2: this.fb.group({
            banana: false,
            kiwi: false,
            durian: false
        }),
        q3: this.fb.group({
            cat: false,
            dog: false,
            dolphin: false
        }),
    });
}
```

The submitted form result may look like this:

```
{ q1:'Trump', q2:{banana:false, kiwi:true, durian:false}, q3:{cat:false, dog:true, dolphin: true} }
```

It seems complicated, moreover, I need to assign custom name to each checkbox (i.e. banana, kiwi, ...).

If I use the *FormArray* approach in Angular4, the submitted result are still complicated. I need some advice, how do you guy dynamically generate a form, with many items, and some of the items are *checkboxes* list?

It will be very easy if I can just get the result in the following fashion:

```
{ q1:'Trump', q2:['kiwi'], q3:['dog', 'dolphin'] }
```

But it seems I can't do it with Angular4... :(

What is the **BEST WAY** to handle complicated checkboxes in Angular4? Is the *FormGroup* approach the only way in Angular4?

Why Angular4 team don't support the `name='checkbox_name[]'` notation for checkbox list? Am I missing something here? What is the new trend in handling complex form? May somebody please explain?

Comment: Can't you just map/reduce the result to whatever you want? Would only be a line or two. The problem with what you want is it's specific to your case. Currently it's the most general it could be - if you want something more specific you transform it to what you want. Rather than having less flexibility in the framework.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought that the *array-like checkboxes list* is the *common implementation* for usual HTML form (learnt from book), just wonder why Angular4 doesn't support this common feature. Wonder if the Angular JSON "style" result are the latest trend in handling checkbox list, and why?